# Замена значений из xml фида Яндекс

Tags: xml, wordpress-плагины

Вопрос, на самом деле, не сложный для знающих людей (к коим я не отношусь).
Я импортирую фид через "Wp All Import". Это объекты недвижимости. В фиде есть обозначение площади "сотка", "гектар", "кв. м".
Как можно эти значения заменить на "сот", "Га", "м²"? А то на выходе получается "участок 200 сотка".

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: <deal-status>прямая продажа</deal-status>
<property-type>жилая</property-type>
<lot-area>
<value>100</value>
<unit>сотка</unit>
</lot-area>

Comment: <unit>сотка</unit> - подобные этому значения нужно поменять, т.е. "сотка" на "сот"

Comment: Какой язык программирования используете? С помощью какой технологии работаете с этим xml?

Comment: Я использую плагин wp all import. Там в конце есть возможность добавления php функций, но этой возможностью я не могу воспользоваться, т.к. я не программист